# Laravel - Model relations validation inside Form Requests

Tags: laravel

I need to do some validations on my `Form Request` based on data from models relations. I came up with a solution, but I don't know if it's the best way to do it. Could someone tell me if there is a better way?

My current controller method:

```php
public function headerMapping(HeaderMappingRequest $request, $workspace, $bulk)
{
    $workspace = auth()->user()
        ->activeWorkspaces()
        ->where('uuid', $workspace)
        ->firstOrFail();

    $bulk = $workspace->messageTemplateBulks()
        ->with(['number', 'template', 'user'])
        ->where('uuid', $bulk)
        ->firstOrFail();

    // Do some logic
    $workspace->doSomeLogic();
    $bulk->doSomeLogic();

    return MessageTemplateBulkResource::make($bulk);
}
```

I cannot use `Implicit Route Model Binding` as I need to get the route parameters models related to the user.

My current Form Request:

```php
class HeaderMappingRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {

        // Needs to add custom validation
        // 'header' => [Rule::requiredIf($bulk->template->featureHeaderIsEnabled())]
        // 'buttons' => [Rule::requiredIf($bulk->template->featureButtonsIsEnabled())]

        return [
            'number' => 'required',
            'header_file' => 'required_if:header_from_file,true|file'
        ];
    }
}
```

I need to do a custom validation based on the bulks templates relations, for this reason I thought about passing these templates to the `Form Request`.

I did the following and it worked, but I don't know if it's the better way to resolve this issue:

Controller method refactoring:

```php
public function headerMapping(HeaderMappingRequest $request, $workspace, $bulk)
{
    // Do some logic
    $request->workspace->doSomeLogic();
    $request->bulk->doSomeLogic();

    return MessageTemplateBulkResource::make($request->bulk);
}
```

Form Request refactoring:

```php
class HeaderMappingRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        $this->workspace = auth()->user()
            ->activeWorkspaces()
            ->where('uuid', $this->route('workspace'))
            ->firstOrFail();

        $this->bulk = $this->workspace->messageTemplateBulks()
            ->with(['number', 'template', 'user'])
            ->where('uuid', $this->route('bulk'))
            ->firstOrFail();

        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'number' => 'required',
            'header' => [Rule::requiredIf($this->bulk->template->featureHeaderIsEnabled())],
            'buttons' => [Rule::requiredIf($this->bulk->template->featureButtonsIsEnabled())],
            'header_file' => 'required_if:header_from_file,true|file'
        ];
    }
}
```

Any thoughts about this?

Comment: looks good, but in case you need to add multiple conditions or perform too many tasks you can also write like a normal if-else statement and in the last return array as it here

Comment: You can retrieve the value for variable `$bulk` via a relationship which hold variable `$workspace`?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not bad, but I would change some stuff, use either of this tips but only one of them:

1. You can use [implicit binding](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#implicit-model-binding-scoping) but you must be using Laravel 8 for it to work as a relationship check.

   - In your case, this would be something like: `Route::get('/header/{activeWorkspaces:uuid}/{messageTemplateBulks:uuid}', ...);`. Maybe, because you are not specifying `User` in the URL as the documentation says, you will have to check if the `activeWorkspaces` is associated with the current `user`, hence `messageTemplateBulks:uuid` will be for sure related to `activeWorkspaces` as the documentation says but you will have to test it.
   - Also, when you `authorize` in your `FormRequest`, check that `activeWorkspaces` is related to the `user` and that's it.
2. Other way is to do what you have done in the `authorize` method, but instead of `firstOrFail` for each query, run `first()` and return `(bool) $this->workspace && (bool) $this->bulk`, so if any of them are `null`, it will not authorize as they are not related.